# Meaning of $\{ a,b \}$, and comparison with $(a,b)$

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, notation, definition

What does $\{a,b\}$ mean in real analysis?

I'm also little bit confused about set definition

Can you tell me the main difference between $(a,b)$ and $\{a,b\}$?

Thank you.

Comment: $(a,b)\neq (b,a)$ but $\{a,b\}=\{b,a\}$.

Comment: $\{a,b\}=\{b,a\}$, all that matters is the elements of the set, namely $a$ and $b$. $(a,b)\ne(b,a)$, now the order in which the elements are listed matters as well.

Comment: The other interpretation is that by $(a,b)$ you mean the *interval*. The notation then means the set of all reals strictly in between $a$ and $b$. Since there is some ambiguity, some people write $\langle a,b\rangle$ for the *ordered pair*, to distinguish it from the interval.

Comment: It's worth noting that $\{a, a\} = \{a\}$, but $(a,a) \neq (a)$. (where $(a)$ is used to denote an ordered *singleton*)

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo Might be worth adding that the notation $(a \,.\,.\, b)$ is becoming more popular to define an interval. Sometimes known as "Wirth interval notation", it follows the convention in certain programming languages. While not widespread, it has the advantage of being particularly unambiguous. Hence you can also use $[a \,.\,.\, b]$ for a closed interval, and similar constructions for half-open ones.

Answer (score 1):

They are both sets, but of different nature. For instance,

$\{a, b\}$ is just a set two points, namely $a$ and $b$.

While $(a,b) = \{ x : a < x < b \} $ is the set of all point $x$ in the reals (since you mentioned real analysis) such that $x$ is between $a$ and $b$, so it contains a lot more points than $\{a, b\} $

$(a,b)$ can also be seen as an ordered pair. That is, a point on the plane $\mathbb{R}^2$. In this case $(a,b)$ is just a single point who lives in $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} $

Comment: Maybe the OP means $(a,b)$ as ordered pairs.

Comment: $\{a,b\}$ doesn't necessarily have two points: if $a=b$, then it only has one point.

Answer (score 0):

The ordered pair $(a,b)$ may be defined as $(a,b)=\{a,\{a,b\}\}$.